# How to add custom error message to Identity Server4 Context

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am developing a mobile app which uses implicit flow for authentication and everything works fine. I have implemented following logic for cancelling user login from login page

```
        var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);

        if (context != null)
        {

            await _interaction.GrantConsentAsync(context, ConsentResponse.Denied);
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
```

This returns "access_denied" as error message to the app. I would like to customize this message so that I can use it for redirection in my mobile app.

I think this can be implemented with the help of ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator, but I do not know how to proceed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
    public class MyAuthorizeRequestValidator : ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
{

    public Task ValidateAsync(CustomAuthorizeRequestValidationContext context)
    {

        var request = context.Result.ValidatedRequest;

        if (context.Result.IsError)
        {
            context.Result = new AuthorizeRequestValidationResult(request, "User Cancelled", "My error Message");
        }

        return Task.FromResult(context);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried what is not working with your CustomAuthorizeRequestValidator

Comment: I have updated ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator code above